# Wait for The Void or get Chthonian Stars?

Tags: traveller

**Has Wildfire's** standalone version of Chthonian Stars (a Lovecraftian sourcebook for the Traveller system published by Mongoose) **"The Void" been cancelled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "The Void" hasn't been cancelled it's just been delayed to 2012 (I believe January) due to issues with Wildfire's publisher Sandstorm.  It's still very much in the pipe at the moment.  (I don't have the link off-hand but there is more info on the Cthulhutech forums.)

Comment: thanks a lot, I do hope they'll manage to keep that deadline. :)

Comment: Me too, they've had the worse luck with publishers.  This is the 3rd one to flake out on them now!